# Class initialization and Dead-Lock in java

Tags: java, deadlock

Following code results in `initialization` of mutually dependent classes `deadlocks` when two `threads` concurrently initialize these `classes`.

I am unable to find the root cause of this problem.

```
class A {
    static boolean x = B.b;
    static boolean a = true;
}

class B {
    static boolean b = true;
    static {
        if (A.a)
            throw new Error();
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new A();
            }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                new B();
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Please help me understand the root cause of this dead lock and how to fix it.

Comment: For one, you're accessing the same variables from multiple threads without synchronization

Comment: if it is a race condition then why always results into deadlock ?

Comment: This warning from IntelliJ  may shed some light: [line `x = B.b`] `uses of non-final static variables during initialization of a class. Such uses may make the semantics of the code dependent on order of class creation, may cause variables to be used before initialized, and generally cause extremely difficult and confusing bugs. `

Answer (score 1):

Dead lock occurs when two threads holds different locks and try to aquire the lock holding by others.

In this case, it occurs when

- `t1` holds the initialization lock of `class A`, and try to get the initialization lock of `class B`.
- while `t2` holds the initialization lock of `class B`, and try to get the initialization lock of `class A`.

---

You can avoid the race condition by executing `t1` and `t2` in order:

```
t1.start();
t1.join();

t2.start();
t2.join();
```

---

More details from [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock
> LC.
>
> ....
>
> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock
> LC. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java
> Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is
> then as follows:
>
> 1. Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves
>    waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.
> 2. ...